# Copying Pandas DF row to next row with modify one cell value based on range

Tags: pandas, dataframe, range

I have built a dataframe that has multiple rows.  Each row has three columns that specify a range i.e. start/stop/step plus other parameters.

I would like copy the row and create a column that goes through the range values. i.e

Original DF would look like:

```
[A, B, C, D, 0, 10, 1]
```

With the last three columns settings for range i.e. start value, stop value, and step value

The output would be

```
[A, B, C, D, 0]
[A, B, C, D, 1]
[A, B, C, D, 2]
......`
```

I've found plenty of how to copy the row.  But I would like to also append the specific column based on the range.

I have no idea where to start.  Can I make a list or use the range function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with list comprehension for `new` column by `range`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["A","F"],
                   "b": ["B",'G'],
                   "c": ["C",'T'],
                   "d": ["D","R"],
                   "start": [0,4],
                   "stop": [10,8],
                   "step": [1,2]
})


cols = ['start','stop','step']
df['new'] = [range(*x) for x in df[cols].to_numpy()]

df = df.explode('new').drop(cols, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    a  b  c  d new
0   A  B  C  D   0
1   A  B  C  D   1
2   A  B  C  D   2
3   A  B  C  D   3
4   A  B  C  D   4
5   A  B  C  D   5
6   A  B  C  D   6
7   A  B  C  D   7
8   A  B  C  D   8
9   A  B  C  D   9
10  F  G  T  R   4
11  F  G  T  R   6
```

Another idea is create helper DataFrame and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) original, only necessary default indices:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

cols = ['start','stop','step']
df = (df.join(pd.DataFrame([(i, j) for i, x in enumerate(df[cols].to_numpy()) 
                                   for j in range(*x)], 
                          columns=[None, 'new'])
       .set_index(None))
      .drop(cols, axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df)

    a  b  c  d  new
0   A  B  C  D    0
1   A  B  C  D    1
2   A  B  C  D    2
3   A  B  C  D    3
4   A  B  C  D    4
5   A  B  C  D    5
6   A  B  C  D    6
7   A  B  C  D    7
8   A  B  C  D    8
9   A  B  C  D    9
10  F  G  T  R    4
11  F  G  T  R    6
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you so much!  Ironically I used the explode feature before in my code to get this and forgot about that feature.  I ended up using a for/while loop to get it to work.  Do you know which way would be better?  I guess I've read modifying in a for loop with index is slower.....

Comment: @2ski4life7 - the best is test it, but obviously loop in pandas are slow.